# Python property does not set

Tags: python, properties

Here is the code:

```
def Property(func):
     return property(**func())

class A:
     def __init__(self, name):
          self._name = name

     @Property
     def name():
          doc = 'A''s name'

          def fget(self):
               return self._name

          def fset(self, val):
               self._name = val

          fdel = None

          print locals()
          return locals()

a = A('John')
print a.name
print a._name
a.name = 'Bob'
print a.name
print a._name
```

Above produces the following output:

```
{'doc': 'As name', 'fset': <function fset at 0x10b68e578>, 'fdel': None, 'fget': <function fget at 0x10b68ec08>}
John
John
Bob
John
```

The code is taken [from here](http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2008/aug/11/the-python-property-builtin/).

Question: what's wrong? It should be something simple but I can't find it.

**Note:** I need property for complex getting/setting, not simply hiding the attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that `fset` doesn't set `name` instead of `_name`? Easy mistake to make, and would explain your symptoms..

Comment: @MartijnPieters 99.9% I just copied the code and the output produced by this code =)

Comment: Any reason to do this strange way of defining properties rather than just using `@property def name(...): "docstr" \n    getter`, `@name.setter def name(...): setter`?

Comment: @delnan It's the tutorial he linked to that does that...

Comment: @delnan The reason is to have one big `def` instead of two (or three, or four) small `def`'s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation for `property()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) states:

> Return a property attribute for new-style classes (classes that derive from object).

Your class is not a new-style class (you didn't inherit from object). Change the class declaration to:

```
class A(object):
    ...
```

and it should work as intended.

Comment: Note that under Python 3.x, all classes are new-style by default, so this won't be a problem (although it doesn't hurt to subclass from `object` anyway).

Comment: Wow it works! I was even more confused by fact that property _did_ get the value properly, so I had no idea that it was `property` function itself what failed.

Answer (score 1):

(Posted above) Use this format:
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = "nameless"

    @property
    def name(self):
        """I'm the 'name' property."""
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

    @name.deleter
    def name(self):
        del self._name
```